# Permission mapping issue

Tags: android, permissions

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, the permissions are claimed as:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

While in Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> Application info  (and also in Google Play) the permissions are claimed as `Fine (GPS) location`.

The problem is where can I find the mappings from one format to another? And is it possible that one permission maps to more than one permissions in another format?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Read the documentation on permissions and then update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` Is the permission for the GPS. (Aka your location).

The fact that it says fine (GPS) location is just to make it user friendly so they understand what it means.

Im not sure how this is a problem..

More info on permissions and what they do (with brief descriptions that the user will see similar of) can be found  [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

[Here is a detailed description as to what each one does, and the exact messages the user will see.](http://techpp.com/2010/07/30/android-apps-permissions-secure-private-data/) It doesnt say the xml permission that goes with it, but they aren't hard to figure out.

Comment: thanks to your comment. The reason I want to find the mapping is I want to collect as many as permission information from adroid apps and do some statistical analysis work. So far I collect many apps (apk files) outside the google play, from which I can got the permissions from AndroidManifest.xml; while I also collect many apps infomation from goole play - I got the permissions from the description in the web page (I can not get the AndroidManifest.xml files of the paid apps). That's why I want to uniform these two formats.

Comment: The first link I provided is probably best then, to help you match them together. Are you gathering the info manually, and tabling it up. Or automated? If my answer was of use, Consider hitting the correct answer button (tick on left). Thanks.

Comment: I wrote some code to gather all the information automatically. The first link you shared can help me, but the descriptions are not the same as that on the google play. I need to manually mapping them (this is fine), and then prove my mapping are correct (which is not easy). I will accept your answer if there is no better answer. Thank you.

Comment: The second link shows the descriptions of google play after the `-` in the sub headings. :). Cool. Good luck.